# wait()/Notify abnormal behaviour for current thread while receiving notifications

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

```
private boolean getNodeReachability(final String ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(!nodeReachabilityStatusMap.containsKey(ip)){
        statusAvailable = Boolean.FALSE;
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    if(nodeReachabilityStatusMap.containsKey(ip)){
                        statusAvailable = Boolean.TRUE;
                        notifyAll();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();

        while(statusAvailable==Boolean.FALSE){
            try{
                wait(5000); 
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
                Log.addInLog(Log.DBG, ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }

    return nodeReachabilityStatusMap.get(ip);
}
```

Actually `getNodeReachability` function returns the status of node accessible or NOT , which is being maintained in `nodeReachabilityStatusMap` , which i am updating in other section of code on getting notifications.
Problem is if notifications are getting delayed then i need to wait till i find the entry in this map. So i am spawnning the new thred(inside the function) which is checking and notifying the current thread. I am not using synchronized keyword.So how it will behave and any right way to do it.

Comment: You're not telling us what is wrong.  Based on the code you're getting a `IllegalMonitorStateException`

Comment: Actually i am bit confused that whether we can apply wait/Notify within synchronized block OR can use independently??

Comment: Exception is not abnormal at all.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking thread has to hold object's monitor lock to invoke `wait()`, `notify()` and `notifyAll()` on that object. So you have to synchronize your code on some object and use it for you synchronization eg.

```
synchronized(someObject){ // can be "this" or anything that is not null and primitive 
    someObject.wait()
}

// on another thread

synchronized(someObject){
    someObject.notify();
}
```

IMHO spawning new thread is totally unnececery since everything you are doing in new thread can be done in thread invoking it.

Comment: But one doubt , say after i make the given function synchronized , and inside that function i am spawnning new thread that will check for entry in hashmap , if its there , i need to notify. So what will be the behaviour. I mean our module is like this    `synchronized(someObject){ // can be "this" or anything that is not null and primitive 
\n new Thread(){\n public void run(){\n //if entry present\n notify();}}.start();\n      someObject.wait()}
}

Comment: synchronized methods are the same as synchronized blocks on `this` object.